# Images in collection view changing during download of data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view that shows items from a remote MySQL database.

Each item has an ImageView that shows also an image from a remote URL.

There is a small issue while loading the items, the image shown at each item is changing for a while, may be during the time all data are loading from the internet. Then the image shown is the correct image.

Here you have the code for the View Controller:

**Function called to download all data for the collection view:**

```
func downloadJSONDispositivos(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    let latitud_usuario = self.defaults.float(forKey: "mi_latitud")
    let longitud_usuario = self.defaults.float(forKey: "mi_longitud")
    
    
    let lati = String(format: "%f", latitud_usuario)
    
    
    let longi =  String(format: "%f", longitud_usuario)
    
    print("Latitud en descarga ",lati)
   print("Longitud en descarga ",longi)
    
    let url_dispo = URL(string: "../telefonia_todos_IOS.php?id=0&lat="+lati+"&lon="+longi)
     
    
    
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url_dispo!) { (data,response,error) in

        
         
     if error == nil {
         do {
            
          self.dispositivosSorted = try JSONDecoder().decode([Dispositivos].self, from: data!)
            print("dispositivos bajados ",data as Any)
             
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 completed()
             }
             
         }catch{
             print("Error disp:",error)
         }
         
     }
     }.resume()
     
      
 }
```

And here you have the collection view methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        //You only apply the changes to collectionViewMarcas
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewDispositivos {
            let padding: CGFloat =  50
            let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

            return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: 242)
        }
    
    // Here Below Line You need To return collectionViewMarcas cell size
    return CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if collectionView == collectionViewMarcas {
            return marcas.count
        }
        
        if filtrados {
            return dispositivosFiltrados.count
        }
        
            return dispositivosSorted.count
        
           
        
    }
           
           
     
    
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == self.collectionViewMarcas {
         
                let marca = marcas[indexPath.row].nombre
            
            self.searchBar.text = marca
              searchBar.delegate?.searchBar?(searchBar, textDidChange: marca)
           
            print(marca)
        }
        else {
        let disposito_pulsado_id = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].id_dispositivo
        let foto1 = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto_dispositivo
        let foto2 = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto2
        let foto3 = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto3
        let foto4 = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto4
        let foto5 = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto5
        
        let nombre_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].nombre_usuario
        let foto_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto_usuario
        let direccion_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].direccion
        let facebook_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].facebook
        let instagram_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].instagram
        let twitter_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].twitter
        let estrellas_usuario = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].num_estrellas
        let usuario_dispositivo = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].usuario_dispositivo
        let logo_marca = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].logo_marca
        let modelo = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].modelo_del_dispositivo
        let precio = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].precio_dispositivo
        let capacidad = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].capacidad
        let ram = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].ram
        let color = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].color
        let garantia = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].garantia
        let estado = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].estado
        let comentarios = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].comentarios
        let modelo_id = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].modelo_dispositivo
        let nombre_marca = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].nombre_marca
            let localizacion = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].localizacion
            print("localizacion en telefonia ",localizacion)
        
        
        print("MODELO ID ",modelo_id)
        
        
        self.defaults.set(foto1, forKey: "foto1")
        self.defaults.set(foto2, forKey: "foto2")
        self.defaults.set(foto3, forKey: "foto3")
        self.defaults.set(foto4, forKey: "foto4")
        self.defaults.set(foto5, forKey: "foto5")
        self.defaults.set(nombre_usuario, forKey: "detalle_nombre_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(foto_usuario, forKey: "detalle_foto_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(direccion_usuario, forKey: "detalle_direccion_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(facebook_usuario, forKey: "detalle_facebook_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(instagram_usuario, forKey: "detalle_instagram_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(twitter_usuario, forKey: "detalle_twitter_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(estrellas_usuario, forKey: "detalle_estrellas_usuario")
        self.defaults.set(usuario_dispositivo, forKey: "detalle_usuario_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(logo_marca, forKey: "detalle_logo_marca_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(modelo, forKey: "detalle_modelo_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(precio, forKey: "detalle_precio_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(color, forKey: "detalle_color_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(capacidad, forKey: "detalle_capacidad_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(ram, forKey: "detalle_ram_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(garantia, forKey: "detalle_garantia_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(estado, forKey: "detalle_estado_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(comentarios, forKey: "detalle_comentarios_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(modelo_id, forKey: "detalle_modelo_id_dispositivo")
        self.defaults.set(nombre_marca, forKey: "detalle_nombre_marca_dispositivo")
            
            self.defaults.set(localizacion, forKey: "detalle_localizacion_dispositivo")
            
            
            let disposito_pulsado_nombre = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].nombre
            print(disposito_pulsado_id)
            self.defaults.set(disposito_pulsado_id, forKey: "dispositivo_pulsado_id")
            print(disposito_pulsado_nombre)
            let logeado_actual = self.defaults.string(forKey: "logeado")
            if (logeado_actual == nil  ){
                       
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "tel_alarma_sin_sesion", sender: nil)
                   }
            else {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "tel_a_detalle", sender: nil)
            }
            
            
            
            
            
        }
       }
       
       
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewMarcas {
                  let cellMarcas = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "marca", for: indexPath) as! MarcasCollectionViewCell
            
           
            
                   let foto_marca = marcas[indexPath.row].icono
                           
                           
                           
                           let url = URL(string: "https://../iconos/"+foto_marca)
                           
                           UIImage.loadFrom(url: url!) { image in
                               cellMarcas.icono_marca.image = image
                              
                           }
                           
                  
                  return cellMarcas
              }

              else {
                   let cellDisp = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dispositivo", for: indexPath) as! DispositivosCollectionViewCell
                
            
          
                       
                       if filtrados {
                        print("esty en filtrados")
                       
                        let foto_dispos = dispositivosFiltrados[indexPath.row].foto_dispositivo
                                  
                             
                             let modelo = dispositivosFiltrados[indexPath.row].modelo_del_dispositivo
                          let marca_t = dispositivosFiltrados[indexPath.row].nombre
                             cellDisp.modelo_disp.text = marca_t+" "+modelo
                             
                             let precio = dispositivosFiltrados[indexPath.row].precio_dispositivo + " €"
                             
                             
                             cellDisp.precio_disp.text = precio
                             let marca = dispositivosFiltrados[indexPath.row].logo_marca
                             let urlmarca = URL(string: "https://../iconos/"+marca)
                             UIImage.loadFrom(url: urlmarca!) { image in
                                            cellDisp.marca_logo.image = image
                                           
                                        }
                             let urlfoto = URL(string: "https://../dispositivos/"+foto_dispos)
                             
                             UIImage.loadFrom(url: urlfoto!) { image in
                                 cellDisp.foto_disp.image = image
                       }
          
               
            }
                       else{
                       
                                              let foto_dispos = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].foto_dispositivo
                                                        
                                                   
                                                   let modelo = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].modelo_del_dispositivo
                                                   cellDisp.modelo_disp.text = modelo
                                                   
                                                   let precio = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].precio_dispositivo + " €"
                                                   
                                                   
                                                   cellDisp.precio_disp.text = precio
                                                   let marca = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.row].logo_marca
                                                   let urlmarca = URL(string: "https://../iconos/"+marca)
                                                   UIImage.loadFrom(url: urlmarca!) { image in
                                                                  cellDisp.marca_logo.image = image
                                                                 
                                                              }
                                                   let urlfoto = URL(string: "https://../dispositivos/"+foto_dispos)
                                                   
                                                   UIImage.loadFrom(url: urlfoto!) { image in
                                                       cellDisp.foto_disp.image = image
                                             }
            }
cellDisp.foto_disp.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                  return cellDisp
              }
        
                  
       }
```

What should I change to get a smoother loading from the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening due to reuse of collection view cell. Try to add the following code in your cell classes

```
class MarcasCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        
        icono_marca.image = nil
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
}
```

same for other

```
class DispositivosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        
        foto_disp.image = nil
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
}
```

try and let me know if that solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you must implement this delegate method in you tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MarcasCollectionViewCell
    cell.icono_marca.image = nil
    
}
```

this is the delegate in charge of reset cell once is been used and go off the screen.